# Set seed for RAND in BigQuery/sample fixed size in Big Query with seed

Tags: google-bigquery

If I want to sample say 100 records from a table in bigquery, I can do it by

```
WITH random_ordered_rows AS
     (SELECT Text, RAND() as rand_ FROM my_table)
    SELECT AiiaCleanedText from random_ordered_rows ORDER BY rand_ LIMIT 100
```

the issue is that I want to make `RAND()` take a seed.

Some other answers on SO suggests that I can use some hashing algorithm and sort by that, but that would just group all duplicates aswell e.g if I have 50 duplicates then 50% of my sample would consist of that duplicate.

Is there a way to randomply sample `N` objects from a bigquery table and setting a seed without using the TABLESAMPLE, since the table size is changing from day to day thust I can't sample a fraction.

Answer (score -1):

Random with a seed produces the same query of values each time. As there is a database table, an ordering has to be defined, otherwise the numbers would be assigned to different rows.

As BigQuery is multi thread parallel tool, there is no such thing as a seed. However, you can generated a table with random numbers.

```
create or replace table Test.random_seed as 
select *, rand() as rand_ from unnest(generate_array(1,1000)) id
```

Next steps is to assign a row number to your dataset for that an order by one or more column has to be defined. Joining the row number with the id of the table with sample random numbers. Because the data can be larger than sample random table, a `mod` lets repeat the data.

```sql
WITH
  raw_data AS (
  SELECT *, "text" AS Text
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,1000*10)) AS data_col ),
  random_ordered_rows AS (
  SELECT  *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data_col ) as rowid
  FROM raw_data)
SELECT   *
FROM   random_ordered_rows 
LEFT JOIN Test.random_seed
on id=mod(rowid,1000)+1
#ORDER BY rand_ LIMIT 100
```